# EJS finds unexpected ";" while there is none

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Currently, I'm working on a website for testing purposes, but when I'm trying to access the file via browser, in the console there's being thrown an error and I don't know, how to fix that or at least understand it.

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' in E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\views\gamesFile.ejs while compiling ejs
> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
> https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
> at new AsyncFunction ()
> at Template.compile (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
> at Object.compile (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
> at handleCache (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
> at tryHandleCache (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
> at View.render (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
> at Function.render (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (E:\AppData\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)

```js
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Randomsservicebot Games</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>VR spiele in Randoms besitz</h1>
        <div>  
            <table>   
                <tr>
                    <th>Spielename</th>
                    <th>USK</th>
                    <th>Tag</th>
                    <th>Steam</th>
                    <th>Oculus</th>
                    <th>InstantGaming</th>
                </tr>  

                <% list.forEach(async (name) => { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= name.value %></td>
                    <td><%= name.processString.usk %></td>
                    <td><%= name.processString.tag%></td>
                    <td><% name.processString.steam.link != "x" ?%><a href=<%name.processString.steam.link%>><% name.procesString.steam.price == "x" ? %> Kostenlos <%: name.processString.steam.price : %> Nicht verfügbar </a></td>
                    <td>404</td>
                    <td><% name.processString.instantgaming.link != "x" ?%><a href=<%name.processString.instantgaming.link%>><% name.procesString.instantgaming.price == "x" ? %> Kostenlos <%: name.processString.instantgaming.price : %>Nicht verfügbar </a></td>
                </tr>
                <%})%> 
            </table> 
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A general tip - try removing lines / logic until the bug doesn't happen, then gradually bring them back.

Comment: In `<%})%>` add more spaces to make it `<% }) %>`. Also `list.forEach` is synchronous

Comment: @kanuos While it makes it easier to read the whitespace isn't syntactically relevant here.

Comment: @kanuos the async does not change anything in the current context ( its there because of the asynk in ```app.get("/about/games", async (req, res) => {
   const games = await myGameCollection.find({})
    res.render("gamesFile", {async: true, games: games})
    console.log(games) 
})``` @Yarin_007 so u mean i shoud use the regular if else statement instead of the may buging in-line check

Comment: @RandomTimeLP There's no async code in the `forEach` callback.

Comment: I think you may be a little confused about how the EJS gets compiled down. Besides being very difficult to read I'd consider doing the logic for the steam and instantgaming links elsewhere to both simplify those table cells, and it'll also help clarify the error (it's the ternaries).

Comment: @Dave Newton it's just there because my friend mentioned it to try and use that but as expected it did't do anything

Comment: i removed the async and the ? : statement and now i get this error https://pastebin.com/KAPKdwrw

Comment: That's a completely separate issue; not knowing anything about how it's being rendered etc. there's no way to help.